# Fill color of vector drawables that are icons in dialogs or toolbars

Tags: android, vector, android-vectordrawable

What if I would want to use vector drawables as icons in dialogs or logos in toolbars? Then I would use them like this:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.my_vector_drawable);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.my_vector_drawable);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_vector_drawable);
...
```

Am I right?

But here comes up a question: how can I change their fill color without modifying vector xml files?

For instatnce I can change fill color of any vector that is in view by using 'tint' tag in xml or 'setColorFilter()' method in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change fill color not change xml file you must create Drawable instances of this file. This instance get you method to change your file.

**for example:**

```
Drawable myIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.my_vector_drawable);

    myIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor));

    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(myIcon);
    toolbar.setLogo(myIcon);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(myIcon);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: drawable.setColorFilter(int, mode) is only available method in here. which mode should I use?

Comment: i don't understand your question but if you want know more abut Drawable read this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html